# Четырёхсторонний

Tags: орфография

Как пишется "4-х сторонний"? После буквы "х" отступать нужно или вместе? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Только **4-сторонний**.

*Вопрос № 263899   

А Вы не подскажете, как объяснить отсутствие "х" в словах 2-этажный, 3-камерный (а не 2-х этажный, например)?

Евгения-я

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Раздельное написание с буквенным наращением неправомерно вот по какой причине: соответствующие сложные прилагательные пишутся слитно (двухэтажный, трехкамерный), буквенное наращение после цифр принято использовать лишь в одном случае - при обозначении порядковых числительных (2-й, 3-й - второй, третий).*
©gramota.ru