# 4-х сторонний

Tags: орфография

Rак пишется слово "4-х сторонний"? После буквы Х отступать нужно или вместе?
Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Четырёхсторонний](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1801/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%80%d1%91%d1%85%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1):

С "х" — неправильно. Четырёхсторонний — 4-сторонний.